# Program to print some some strings in random order

Tags: c, arrays, string

[this is my code; you can see the errors in the bottom. I know that arrays in C are
seen like pointers, but I'm pretty sure the declarations is right (char str). I don't know why it doesn't print anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWNCx.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 3     
#define M 10

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getchsystem("pause") or input loop */


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    srand(time());      //to generate each run different numbers
    char str [N][M];
    int i,j;
    i=0;

    str [0][0]="good";
    str[1][M]="morning";
    str[2][M]="world";

    for (j=0;j<N; j++) {
        i=rand()%(N-0+1)+1;     //formula to generate randoms numbers
        printf("%s",str[i]);    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C you can't use `=` to copy a string, please use `strcpy`. The `=` syntax can only be used for a string *pointer*, or when initialising an array in the statement where it is defined. You should enable all compiler warnings and act on them. *"I know that arrays in C are seen like pointers"* is a partial truth - when they are passed to a function.

Comment: Note too that `i = rand() % N;` is correct, not `i = rand() % (N+1) + 1;`

Comment: So one way would be to use `strcpy(str[0], "good");` and so on.

Comment: also note that with `str[x][y]` you're accessing a single `char`. A string is a NUL-terminated array of `char`s. Locations `str[0]`, `str[1]`, and `str[2]` each contain `M` `char`s, so your strings can be max `M-1` chars long each (the last char in the string must be 0).

Comment: even if i use strcpy(str[0],"good"); ecc. it doesn't work, I really don't understand. I also tried defining str[N][M]={"hello","good","world"}and then print but nothing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Kudos for posting a minimal program.  But you need to learn to do basic initial debugging.  Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: In the future, post the output from running your program too.  In this case we'd see that you're getting a segmentation violation before generating any output.  Also, sprinkle your program with prints so you can see what line causes the segmentation fault.  In this case, it's the call to `time()`.  You have to fix that before trying to fix anything else!

Comment: @StefanoModenese did you change the random index code? Your code gives `i` in the range `1...4` but it must be in the range `0...2`.

Comment: If you want to permute the strings randomly, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, now it works perfectly fine! Sorry I’m very noob at the moment but I’m looking forward to be better! I learn a lot here from you

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion, -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your code here.

In C, you cannot assign strings using the assignment operator unless it's a string pointer or you're initializing. See [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) for the man page on strcpy.

Using the above method, you can define your strings like so:

```
    strcpy(str[0], "good");
    strcpy(str[1], "morning");
    strcpy(str[2], "world");
```

Your rand function call should also just be 
`i = rand() % N;`

When you were calling str[N][M] you were actually accessing a single character of the string rather than the whole thing. 
ex.

```
str[0][0] = 'g'
str[0][1] = 'o'
str[1][0] = 'm'
str[1][1] = 'o'
```

Comment: Thank you, I have understood that. That’s a pity It still doesn’t work... I have written str[N][M]={“good”,”morning”,”world”} and tried to primt the strings with (for example) printf(“%s”, str[1]). Is any if this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, turn on compilation warnings.  You should get warnings because your code isn't valid.  For example, with gcc I get:

```
randstr.c: In function ?main?:
randstr.c:16:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     str [0][0]="good";
               ^
randstr.c:17:14: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     str[1][M]="morning";
              ^
randstr.c:18:14: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     str[2][M]="world";
```

This is because you are assigning *character string pointers* to `char` elements in the array, and each char element holds one character (generally, 8 bits.)

A simpler way to code this would be to use `char *str[N]` rather than `char str[N][M]`.

But the reason your program crashes with segmentation fault is that `time()` takes an argument, and you're not passing one.  Try `time(NULL)`.

Here's how it would be coded using `char *str[N]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 3

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    srand(time(NULL));      //to generate each run different numbers

    char *str[N];
    int i,j;

    str[0] = "good";
    str[1] = "morning";
    str[2] = "world";

    for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
        i = rand() % N;     //formula to generate randoms numbers
        printf("%s\n",str[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```